# Mod 10 is not working for big values

Tags: php

I'm using the latest  version of php.

```
<?php  $value=2000000002222 % 10; echo $value;

?>
```

I can't get the result 2 instead I'm getting -4.  Why am I getting an incorrect value for the mod operation?

Comment: `echo 2000000002222` - what does that give you?

Comment: same value....  divide option is working perfectly but % is not working for higher values what can i do for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are hitting an integer overflow. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> It is worth noticing that when working with large numbers, most noticably using the modulo operator, the results depend on your CPU architecture.

Also

> Note that operator % (modulus) works just with integers (between -214748348 and 2147483647) while fmod() works with short and large numbers.

Trying using `fmod()` instead of `mod()` since your numbers are larger than the max integer.

Comment: Why buffer overflow? All I see is a floating point rounding, not even an integer overflow.

Comment: php will automatically convert the integer to a float because it is too large which is why the % operator fails to get the mod correctly because it is for integers only

Comment: @JanDvorak "Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing." from the documentation.

Comment: That would be integer overflow, then. Still not a case of buffer overflow.